# How do I upgrade Zend_Framework from 1.9 to 1.10?

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu

How do I upgrade Zend Framework 1.9 to 1.10 in Ubuntu 9.10(k)?

Comment: @Donal Fellows: Yes, it's more of a usage question, but it's programming related because it is a question specific to Zend Framework. Therefore I'd keep it here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you installed it with apt-get (which is silly, IMO).

Uninstall it via apt.

Reinstall it via PEAR:

```
pear channel-discover zend.googlecode.com/svn
pear install zend/zend
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just download the Zend Framework from their site and put it in your php include path.